# consulta a dos bases para registro de usuario

Tags: mysql, php5

les comento el tema. Tengo dos tablas en una base, la primera son los datos del matriculado, la segunda es la que contendrá los datos del usuario del sitio.
Primero planteo un formulario donde pido al DNI.
Paso a una segunda página en donde estará el formulario de registro.
Pero antes de mostrarme dicho formulario debe hacer dos comprobaciones.
La primera es si esta en la base de matriculados.
La segunda es si ya esta registrado, consultando a la tabla usuarios.

Alguna orientación como plantearlo. Gracias a Todos

Comment: Buenas Alejandro. Parece que planteado lo tienes, ahora falta que lo montes. Como sabrás, en SOes se ayuda con código y solución a problemas en código, pero no se hace código a petición, por tanto, quizá deberías empezar por lo básico, intentar montar algo y, si te atascas, preguntar aquí mostrando el código que tienes hasta el momento. Te adjunto el enlace a [mcve] y a [ask] para que le pegues un vistazo, si no lo has hecho aún, y edites la pregunta en consecuencia. Un saludo!.

Comment: Pues, lo primero que tendrías que hacer, como bien te indica @Emerita, es modelar el problema. Hazte el [modelo ER](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modelo_entidad-relaci%C3%B3n) y, a partir de ahí, ya podremos empezar a ayudarte...